# Change custom buttons attributes

Tags: python, kivy

I created a custom button as follows

```
#: import icon kivy.garden.iconfonts.icon
<custom_Button@Button>:
   background_normal: 'icons/backg.png'
   RelativeLayout:
      size: self.parent.width, self.parent.height
      top: self.parent.top
      right: self.parent.right
      Label:
         canvas.before:
            Color:
               rgba: 1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
               pos: self.pos
               size: self.size
               source: 'icons/restaurant.png'
         color: 0,0,0,1
         id: icon_name
         markup: True
         font_size: '20dp'
         text: '{}'.format(icon('ion-settings', 38))
         pos_hint: {'center_y': .5, 'right': .25}
         size_hint: .18, .9
      Label:
         text:'Change Settings'
         id: label
         color: 0,0,0,1
         text_size: self.size
         halign: 'left'
         valign: 'middle'
         font_size: '20dp'
         pos_hint: {'center_y': .5, 'right': 1}
         size_hint: .7, .9
```

i want to be able to pass this (Custom_Button) as a child to different layouts, and change some of the attributes to what i want. Heres what i mean.
for example,

```
GridLayout:
   custom_Button
   custom_Button
   custom_Button
```

But i would like to be able to explicitly change the label icon for the first label in the custom_Button, also the text in the second Label, so that for the three instances of the cutom_Button a different icon and text would be displayed. I really dont know how to achieve this. So please i need some help.
An example code will be very helpful. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do change the class name to something standard, like `CustomButton`. Then, define a new property containing the `icon_source`:

```
<CustomButton@Button>:
    icon_source: 'icons/restaurant.png'
...
```

and refer to it later:

```
Rectangle:
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    source: root.icon_source
```

Then it's simple to change this for every instance, either in `kv` or in python:

```
GridLayout:
    CustomButton:
        icon_source: 'something/else.png'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks alot